# Что делает функция? где может использоваться? пример использования

Tags: javascript

```js
function bind(method, context) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return function() {
    var a = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
    return method.apply(context, a);
  }
}
```

Есть функция, хочу понять что она делает, и где ее применить. Господа кто знает пожалуйста сообщите ))

Comment: Это что-то вроде полифила для уже стандартной `bind` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: для чего можно применить ? )

Comment: Есть функция, которая по-разному вызывается. Следовательно `this` внутри нее будет всегда иметь разные значения. Пропускаем эту функцию через вашу функцию `bind` и получаем на выходе ту же функцию, только у нее `this` всегда будет один и тот же.

Comment: То есть аналог bind, из этого следует он применяется где нужно строго задать контекст ??

Comment: Да, аналог стандартного `bind`, просто где-то стандартный может не поддерживаться, поэтому он реализован "вручную". И да, там, где нужно строго задать контекст.

Comment: А пример короткий можешь накидать, применения ?

Comment: Это уже ответ писать надо, а мне лень :) По ссылке выше куча примеров есть. Да и сейчас уже этот метод вообще редко где используется, как правило.

Comment: Лады,  понял )) спасибо за ответ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это полифилл для старых браузеров, которые не поддерживают метод `bind()`. Использовать есть смысл только в старых версиях браузеров, которые меньше, чем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так как встроенные методы всегда короче и быстрее работают.

 Здесь подробно расписано, зачем метод `bind()` вообще нужен и как его использовать:
https://learn.javascript.ru/bind

А в кратце - он используется, если нужно изменить значение `this` для конкретной функции и/или привязать аргументы - затем эти изменения обычно сохраняются в новой переменной.

Comment: Окей спасибо за коммент! )

Comment: Так же в этом полифилле синтаксис отличается от стандартного. Стандартный: `Function.bind(context, arguments)`, а здесь: `bind(Function, context, arguments)`. То есть кто-то решил поменять местами элементы, чтобы свойство превратить в функцию.